# TableView section seperator line

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I wanted to add separator line into the table view section. Currently the code for the header section view will be:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    header.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [header.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rubik-Regular" size:15.0]];

}
```

[image]

Comment: your back button is on wrong side, please don't do that

Comment: @Lope do you mean the top right back button?

Comment: Yes, that one. It goes against everything users are accustomed to

Comment: @Lope Alright noted, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

would be better to make it there:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = // make header here
    header.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [header.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rubik-Regular" size:15.0]];
    // make a view with height = 1 attached to header bottom
    UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, header.frame.size.height, header.frame.size.width, 1)];
    [separator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [header addSubview:separator];
    return header;
}
```

Comment: the "make header here" means?

Comment: Isn't this UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view; is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't here for a while. Usually in this method I make footer/header view myself. UIView *header = ... /create/load from nib/use cell/etc. You can add the separator in your willDisplayHeaderView too, but in that case I think you maybe have to check is header already contains the separator view. You are welcome.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    let separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.separatorInset.left, y: footerView.frame.height, width: tableView.frame.width - tableView.separatorInset.right - tableView.separatorInset.left, height: 1))
    separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.separatorColor
    footerView.addSubview(separatorView)
    return footerView
}

extension UIColor {
   class var separatorColor: UIColor {
     return UIColor(red: 244.0/255.0, green: 244.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to achieve this in swif :)

Comment: If you want to have the same color as the default separators, i would argue that `separatorView.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor` would be the best way of setting the separator color, since Apple might change the default colors at any time.

Answer (score 3):

I used below code and it worked for me:

- Swift version : 4.2
- Xcode version : 10.3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    let dummyView = UIView() //just a dummy view to return
    let separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.separatorInset.left, y: footerView.frame.height, width: tableView.frame.width - tableView.separatorInset.right - tableView.separatorInset.left, height: 0.5))
    separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    footerView.addSubview(separatorView)

    if section == 1 {    
        return footerView
    }
    return dummyView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height-1, 320, 1); 
UIView *separatorView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame]; 
seperatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow()
[header addSubview:separatorView];
```

Comment: Are you sure? because if you add this lines of code to your code, it should work.

@NurII It's the same answer as your marked as right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found adding a footer view to be the cleanest solution.  Don't forget to include the footer view height in heightForFooterInSection.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 1.0))
    separatorView.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
    return separatorView
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
```